# getting error on creating reactive forms module in angular 15

Tags: angular, frontend, web-development-server, angular15

The error i am getting:

[image]

[image]

I am new on angular. now getting this error when i am binding form with the property.

here is the code of my app

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup,FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
  
  loginVal:FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb : FormBuilder ){

    this.formBinding();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { };

  formBinding(){
    this.loginVal = this.fb.group({
      username:["testuser"],
      userpass:[""],
    });
  }

  display(){
    console.log(this.loginVal.value);
  }

}
```

here is the html

```
<form [formGroup]="loginVal" class="form-group" (ngSubmit)="display()"> 
    <label for="">User Name:</label>
    <input formControlName="username" class="form-control">
    <label for="">Password:</label>
    <input formControlName="userpass" class="form-control">
  
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  
  </form>
```

imports on appmodule.ts

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
    
  ],
```

tried in many ways but failed to bind the property

Update Note: this Problem is solved using "!" (Null assertion) operator

Comment: Use non null assertion operator to prevent taht error:loginVal!:FormGroup

Comment: Thanks the problem is already solved using null assertion operator,

i have another query which is can i use POJO class for angular for better accessing data ?

Comment: Yes You can use

Comment: Can you tell me a bit of detail, please? How can I implement that? or if you have any good resources for learning the process would be great.

if possible then please share your discord or telegram

Comment: Does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398877/how-do-i-declare-a-model-class-in-my-angular-2-component-using-typescript?